# How to handle User/Group relationships in SailsJS using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm new to both SailsJS (using v0.10) and MongoDB and trying to implement the function of a User/Group relationship. Can't get my head around it.

This is what I try to implement:

- A **User** can be a member of one or more **Groups**.
- A **Group** can have one or more members (**Users**).
- Each member in a **Group** can have a role, either *Admin* or *Normal*
- When getting a **User** also return all **Groups** the user is a member of, as a property.
- When getting a **Group** also return all **Users** in the group, as a property.

I have the follwing models.

**User.js**

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        // Email, this is used as login credentials 
        email: {
            type: 'email', // Email type will get validated by the ORM
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },

        // The name of the person, used to simplify identification
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

    }
};
```

**Groups.js**

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

        description: {
            type: 'string'
        },

    }

};
```

I need some help with how to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: For the schemas in mongodb take a look at [these blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) it's three parts. I think they will help you.

Comment: Thanks! Have reda it and will try to prototype something from the ides I got.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using many-to-many associations in Sails/Waterline. For more information see: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/ManytoMany.html

**User.js**

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        // Email, this is used as login credentials 
        email: {
            type: 'email', // Email type will get validated by the ORM
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },

        // The name of the person, used to simplify identification
        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

        // Groups
        groups: {
            collection: 'groups',
            via: 'members'
        }

    }
};
```

**Groups.js**

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        name: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true
        },

        description: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        // Members
        members: {
            collection: 'user',
            via: 'groups'
        }

    }

};
```

Comment: This does not work all the way, beacuse I can't specify the role each user have in a group using this technic.